# Celery Flower not found js files

Tags: python, django, flower

I just started to use Flower for Celery task monitoring. Everything is working well on locally. But when I deploy my code to server, and try to open flower page I received the following error

```
[pid: 6442|app: 0|req: 20/20] 46.19.100.110 () {44 vars in 935 bytes}       
[Thu Mar 10 06:38:39 2016] GET /static/js/bootstrap-collapse.js?v=e8ddac0b5dd49cfbcf7d3ca8b0098d7b => generated 1852 bytes in 22 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 80 bytes (1 switches on core 0)

Not Found: /static/js/bootstrap-carousel.js

[pid: 6442|app: 0|req: 21/21] 46.19.100.110 () {44 vars in 935 bytes}      
[Thu Mar 10 06:38:39 2016] GET /static/js/bootstrap-carousel.js?v=fc8cbc40f39316b8b567b3b96efe9044 => generated 1852 bytes in 24 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 80 bytes (1 switches on core 0)

Not Found: /static/js/d3.min.js
[pid: 6442|app: 0|req: 22/22] 46.19.100.110 () {44 vars in 911 bytes}    
[Thu Mar 10 06:38:39 2016] GET /static/js/d3.min.js?v=eb68d3d1035789d336b285373046b550 => generated 1816 bytes in 23 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 80 bytes (1 switches on core 0)

Not Found: /static/js/rickshaw.min.js

[pid: 6442|app: 0|req: 23/23] 46.19.100.110 () {44 vars in 923 bytes}  
[Thu Mar 10 06:38:39 2016] GET /static/js/rickshaw.min.js?v=fc927b6dd64118caa563b711bcb2f130 => generated 1834 bytes in 21 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 80 bytes (1 switches on core 0)

Not Found: /static/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js

[pid: 6442|app: 0|req: 24/24] 46.19.100.110 () {44 vars in 955 bytes}    
[Thu Mar 10 06:38:39 2016] GET /static/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js?v=8880b6a34ee02b5cb6a75f92b3a7ddc9 => generated 1882 bytes in 19 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 80 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
Not Found: /static/js/flower.js
```

Any ideas?

this is nginx config file

```
upstream admin_backend {
    server {{ backend_host }}:{{ backend_port }};
}

upstream flower_backends {
    server {{ backend_host }}:{{ flower_port }};
}

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name     admin{{ suffix }}.skycryptor.com;
    rewrite     ^ https://admin{{ suffix }}.skycryptor.com last;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name admin{{ suffix }}.skycryptor.com;

client_max_body_size 100M;
location / {
    uwsgi_pass admin_backend;
    include uwsgi_params;
}

location /flower {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_pass http://flower_backends;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_next_upstream error;
}

location /robots.txt {
    alias /opt/static/robots.txt;
}
}
```

I think Flower is running normallu, this is message from log file

```
Executing /opt/worker/runenv/bin/celery --app=skyworker flower --port=5555 in /opt/worker/runenv
```

Comment: How did you deploy? Also add your server (nginx/apache) configuration to the question.

Comment: I edited and added nginx config file in my question

Comment: I am assuming you have latest version of `flower`? Latest version of flower does not support a URL path like '/flower' you must run it on a full domain like 'flower.skycryptor.com'. Or you can use earlier versions of flower that support URL paths like '/flower'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In earlier versions of flower, it had a command line parameter `--url-prefix=flower`. It enabled users to run flower on a URL path like `/flower`. In recent versions this parameter deprecated and flower's pypi version (0.8.4) can only run on a sub domain like `flower.example.com` but not on a URL path like `example.com/flower`.

In the master branch of [github repo of flower](https://github.com/mher/flower), its author has [restored](https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/414#issuecomment-189577996) the `--url-prefix` parameter (12 days ago, so it is not on pypi yet, so pip install flower will pull older version), see this [issue](https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/414) (issue was reported by me).

So what you need to do is install flower from master branch of github repo instead of pypi, and specify `--url-prefix=flower` in command line when running flower.

Comment: Info about `--url-prefix` is still actual in 2022. Thanks!